# how to load or read local files in Emscripten without using Preload-file?

Tags: javascript, electron, preload, emscripten

i have cpp file contains open file and read the content that function i have to use in web browser using Emscripten. i already done **preload** virtual file access from my current directory to load the files but still i want to load files from other directory also when i tried i am getting failure how to achieve this ?

> here my compiled cpp code

```
emcc --bind flvNew.cpp -o flv5.js --preload-file Sample
```

i expect alternate file access that should read all files from my computer